# SQL query returning null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I run this query, it returns null value for ID. The code is supposed to get the max value in the id column.

```
2013-06-13-0001
2013-06-13-0002
```

It should get the `2013-06-13-0002` (because of the `0002` being a greater value than the `0001`) for the id column.. the query is supposed to get the max id and add 1 to it.

```
SELECT 
   ID = LEFT(max(ID), 10) + '-' + 
        RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(max(ID), 4)) + 1), 4)
FROM John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment
WHERE
   LEFT(ID, 10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Getdate(), 20)
```

Comment: tagged the question as `sql-server`.

Comment: try use the column remaining... like this select field as new_field_name from table

Comment: Well the problem is.. the same exact code was working yesturday but when I restarted the computer and tried to run again it started returning null.. I don't need to alter the code, Im just wondering why it's returning null instead of the maxvalue and adding 1 to it.

Comment: @user2484066 Your `WHERE` clause is dependent on the date, so it's very possible there is no data with today's date but there was with yesterdays.

Comment: Perhaps it's this? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259202(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @JNK yes you are right.. I just changed the actual date in the data to today and it works now.

Comment: Now.. I just need to figure out how to put this query into an asp.net function so that it calls the query to return it into a textbox. Thanks guys..

Comment: I suggest you profile this query carefully if performance is an issue.  WHERE clauses involving functions on the left side of the equal sign do not optimize well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172984.aspx

Comment: Ah so you are trying to create some date dependant `IDENTITY` scheme so `ID` is like `2013-06-140-0001`? I wouldn't bother anyway as this is difficult to get right under conditions of concurrency but looks like you will get this problem every day unless you change the query to handle the first one of the day. (when `MAX(ID)` is `NULL`)

Comment: @MartinSmith May you kindly change the code so that it would work everyday, for me?

Comment: The whole concept looks fundamentally flawed unless this is a single user system. How are you protecting against two users simultaneously doing the `SELECT` and getting given the same "next" identity value? I would just have a separate column for `create_date` and have a normal `IDENTITY` column.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to select a new custom ID like this before you actually insert the record, as someone else may insert that same value before you.  So here's how you can potentially run your table inserts:

```
insert into John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment (MyCol1, MyCol2, ID)
select @MyFormValue1,
    @MyFormValue2,
    convert(varchar(10), current_timestamp, 20)
        + '-'
        + right('000' + cast(cast(right(coalesce(max(ID), '0'), 4) as smallint) + 1 as varchar(4)), 4)
from John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment
where ID like convert(varchar(10), current_timestamp, 20) + '%'; -- like may use an index in this case
```

We're coming up with the ID during the insert, not before.  This should mostly solve the contention issue (heck, you can only have 9,999 inserts per day anyway with that 4-digit ID suffix) and `coalesce` will take care of the case where you have no data yet today (and insert ID "...-0001").

If you need to select this record immediately after the insert to display to the user, you could use the [`output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) keyword.

If it does not already have one, adding a unique constraint of some sort to this ID column is mandatory. At least then you could handle the exception and allow the user to try the insert again if contention is still an issue (I'm not expert enough to say that these inserts could *never* collide or if you should lock the table to prevent such a thing).

I agree with @MartinSmith and I would rather use a create date column with an identity column (or maybe 2012's [sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)), and thus be able to calculate this ID column.  I also understand that some part numbering schemes should just be stored, and sometimes skipped numbers aren't valid (unless there are deletes).

I welcome feedback from those that know more.

Comment: would I need to put anything in the mycol1, mycol2? and what do I need to put in myformvalue1 and 2?

Comment: Those are simply generic example placeholders of the other columns your table may have. I was imagining you were inserting from a web app. Only your non-null columns are necessary for an insert. You could even run the select by itself to insert later, but that's exactly against my first words of caution.

Comment: Oh right, I took out the placeholder for mycol. and just left it as ID. Yes, I'm inserting it from a web app. Still don't get what the @myform is though.. sorry D: could you explain what I can do with that?